# Angular $http.get changes from select box

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm not sure if this is going to make sense, I spent some time trying to research the answer I require.

I'm wanting to know if it is possible in angular to change the URL requested from a $http.get request from a value of a select box.

So I have built a simple controller which gets a JSON file and passes the response in to the scope, then I pass that data in to the view.

But I will have several JSON files which I want to load on selection of an option from a drop down and reload the data.

My Angular is fairly basic, so i'm unsure if this is at all possible to do on the fly?

```
var app = angular.module('serverstats', []);
 app.controller('ServerController', function($scope, $http){
 var apiFeed = $('.apiSelecter').val();
  $http.get(apiFeed).then(function(response){
$scope.status = response.data;

$scope.server = [];
angular.forEach($scope.status.servers, function(svr) {
    $scope.server.push(svr);
 })
console.log('server', $scope.server);

  });
});


<select class="apiSelecter">
  <option value="/test.json">Data File 1</option>
  <option value="/test1.json">Data File 2</option>
  <option value="/test2.json">Data File 3</option>
</select>


<div ng-controller="ServerController" id="server-stats" class="server-stats">
      <div ng-repeat="stat in server" class="container" ng-cloak>
        <div class="stats-box col-md-2">
          <p class="lead">Server Name: {{ stat.serverName }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stats-box col-md-2">
          <p class="lead">Response Time: {{ stat.responseTime }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stats-box col-md-2">
          <ul>
          <p class="lead">Ports</p>
            <li><p class="lead">{{ stat.ports.port1 }}</p></li>
            <li><p class="lead">{{ stat.ports.port2 }}</p></li>
            <li><p class="lead">{{ stat.ports.port3 }}</p></li>
            <li><p class="lead">{{ stat.ports.port4 }}</p></li>
            <li><p class="lead">{{ stat.ports.port5 }}</p></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Apologies now included code

Comment: You probably can, but we can't help without seeing your code first. So please [edit] your question and include your code (Create a [mcve])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can.

HTML :

```
<select id="mySelect" ng-model="myValue" ng-change="myMethod()">
                    <option ng-repeat="o in options" value="{{o.url}}">{{o.label}}</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.options = [
   {url : 'www.google.com', label: 'google'},
   {url : 'www.facebook.com', label:'facebook'}
]
$scope.myMethod = function() {
    console.log($scope.myValue);
    //HTTP Resquest here
}
```

The ng-change attribute will trigger when you change the selected option. The ng-model allows you to store the current value in memory.

After your HTTP request (in then `.then`) you can load your JSON and all the stuff you do.

NB : if your select is a Materialize one, use the angular-materialize library and use

```
<select id="mySelect" ng-model="myValue" ng-change="myMethod()">
                        <option ng-repeat="o in option" value="{{o.url}}" material-select watch>{{o.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexi, I will give that a go now

Comment: I might be doing something really dumb here but i'm getting myValue is undefined

Comment: @MatthewWhite They forgot a small thing: `console.log($scope.myValue);` :)

Comment: @MatthewWhite Cool! Please consider accepting AlexiC answer if it helped you

Comment: Oh yes my bad forgot the $scope on myValue. I will edit thins soon ;)